# Generate a page on openstreetmap.org as a bounding box with markers

Tags: openstreetmap, georeferencing

openstreetmap.org URLs are generated using a singular geolocation coordinate.

Hoever, the goal is to generate a (pre-calculated) bounding box with 2-4 markers (geocoordinates) on the map.  There are a number of references to tools and libraries, such as around slippyMap, however the amount of services goes beyond the needs (the viewer is free to be interested in other data of the bbox) & we just want to generate the link with a URL to openstreetmap.

I had a recollection of seeing such documentation years ago, but cannot find it at present.  Is this still possible? & where is the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

found instead the `leaflet` javascript documentation and the `fitBounds` command sepcifically

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="min-height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    const map = L.map('map').fitBounds([
      [corner1.lat, corner1.lon],
      [corner2.lat, corner2.lon]
]);
    const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);


    const marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);


</script>
```